# ArrayList Data Structure – Daily Temperature

Tags: java, arraylist

I've looked everywhere on stack overflow and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Please Help! Thank you so much for your time.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;    

public class DailyTempandAverage {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> days = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Double> temperatures = new ArrayList<>();

    days.add("Monday");
    days.add("Tuesday");
    days.add("Wednesday");
    days.add("Thursday");
    days.add("Friday");
    days.add("Saturday");
    days.add("Sunday");

     System.out.print("Enter the temperature for: " +days);



    double sum = 0.0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < temperatures.size(); i++) {
        sum += temperatures.get(i);
    }

    double average = (double) sum / temperatures.size();

    System.out.println("Average temperatures = " + average);

    }
}
```

This is my Output:
run:

```
Enter the temperature for: [Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday]Average temperatures = NaN
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

This is what I need it to do that it's not doing all of it:

Store data in the form of daily temperature for one week.  Your program should prompt the user for the day of the week (Monday through Sunday) and the temperature for each day. Store the day and temperature in two different ArrayLists. The output for your program should provide the temperature for each day and the weekly average.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to Java and I have aspirations of being a Data Scientist. Thanks again kind stranger.

Answer (score 1):

You never enter any data into `temperatures`.

Therefore `temperatures.size() == 0`

Anything divided by 0 is `NaN`

So the code is doing exactly what you told it to.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Sorry. I don't have control over who down votes what. Are you implying that I'm responsible for all the downvotes? (I'm not), but so what if I was? - I lose 2 points just the same as the person I'm downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

You do not use your scanner to read in your temparatures

try

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> days = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Double> temperatures = new ArrayList<>();

        days.add("Monday");
        days.add("Tuesday");
        days.add("Wednesday");
        days.add("Thursday");
        days.add("Friday");
        days.add("Saturday");
        days.add("Sunday");

         for (String day : days) {
             System.out.println("Enter the temperature for: " + day);
             double temp = in.nextDouble();
             temperatures.add(temp);
         }

         double sum = 0.0;
         for ( int i = 0; i < temperatures.size(); i++) {
             sum += temperatures.get(i);
         }

         double average = (double) sum / temperatures.size();

         System.out.println("Average temperatures = " + average);
```

**edit**

Although IMHO I think it would be better to use a `Map <String, Double>` so that you only need to have one Collection

Answer (score -1):

**The below code achieves desired functionality**

```
public class Test {
static LinkedHashMap<String, Double> weekTemp;

public static void main(String args[]) {

    weekTemp = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    setWeekDays(); //This method sets all the days with default temperature 0.0
    storeTemperature(); //This method stores all the data provided by user
    calculateAvgTemp();//This method calculates average temperature and prints all days' temperature


}
private static void setWeekDays() {
    weekTemp.put("Monday", 0.0);
    weekTemp.put("Tuesday", 0.0);
    weekTemp.put("Wednesday", 0.0);
    weekTemp.put("Thursday", 0.0);
    weekTemp.put("Friday", 0.0);
    weekTemp.put("Saturday", 0.0);
    weekTemp.put("Sunday", 0.0);
}

private static void storeTemperature() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (String day : weekTemp.keySet()
            ) {
        System.out.print("Enter Temperature for " + day + " --> ");
        Double dayTemp = sc.nextDouble();
        weekTemp.put(day, dayTemp);
    }
}
private  static void calculateAvgTemp() {
    Double totalTemp = 0d;
    for (String s : weekTemp.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("Day--> " + s + " Temp--> " + weekTemp.get(s));
        totalTemp = totalTemp + weekTemp.get(s);
    }
    System.out.println("Average temperature of week --> " + totalTemp / 7);
}



}
```